# How to correctly display HTML page in browser and mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have a following HTML page. In this page I face different problems in desktop and mobile browser.

1. In desktop browser all things is display, but the image is too big. If I try to make it small then it becomes to small for mobile. So how to achive it, so the icon becomes suitable for both places?
2. In mobile browser `border-bottom-style` not dispaly but in desktop browser it display. So what is the problem?

HTML:

```
<body style="height:100%">
  <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;" class="homebackground">
    <tr height="10%">
      <td colspan="3" style="background:url(../../stylesheets/images/user_male.png) no-repeat; background-size: contain;border-bottom-style:solid;border-color: #129AA2; border:1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="80%" style="background:url(../../stylesheets/images/Logo_with_Blu_bg.png); background-size:98% 88%;">
      <td colspan="3">
        <table style="width:100%; height:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr style="height:20%;">
            <td align="right" class="mainbodyup"><img src="../../stylesheets/images/phone.png"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="mainbodyup"><img src="../../stylesheets/images/groupchat.png"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr height="60%">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr height="20%">
            <td class="mainbodyup"><img src="../../stylesheets/images/recent.png"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="mainbodyup"><img src="../../stylesheets/images/search.png"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10%">
      <td colspan="3" style="background:url(../../stylesheets/images/setting_footer.png) no-repeat; background-size: contain;border-top-style:solid;border-color: #129AA2; border:1">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.mainbodyup
{
    height:20%;
    width:33%; 
    padding:0px;
}
.mainbodyup img
{
  max-width:30%;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) {
.mainbodyup
{
    height:20%;
    width:33%; 
    padding:0px;
}
.mainbodyup img
{
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
}
```

**LATER EDIT**

i change my css to media  queries. now the problem i face is the last one media query is work.if i interchange then then also the result is same.both queries work fine seperately but if i put them together then last one is work, so what is the problem?

Comment: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your media queries the other way around. First you target screens with minimum 100px and then min 768px. This way, the later will override the first one

Comment: so what is the solution? i interchange them,but same result last one override it.

Comment: if you interchange them you will have the max-width of .mainbodyup img 100% on devices with sceens larger than 100px(a phone) and override with 30% on screens larger than 768 (a tablet/desktop)

Comment: the problem is suppose i remove css of `@media only screen and (min-width: 100px)` then another one is work fine for desktop and if i remove `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)` then another one is working fine for mobile.but if both queries are present then last one is working so what is the solution for it?

Comment: I just tried in Chrome and the media query works just fine. What browser are you using? If you lower the max-width for desktop even more you'll see a better result

Comment: chrome and tested it with firefox too,still same result.

Comment: see [http://jsfiddle.net/B8T66/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/B8T66/3/).i change max width for `@media only screen and (min-width: 100px)` and it affect `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41617/discussion-between-schopy-and-ds9)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the *same* HTML and CSS for every platform (Desktop and Mobile), you should use **CSS media queries**. You could read this as a [good start on the subject.](http://verekia.com/initializr/responsive-template)

**Media queries** look like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    .mainbodyup img
    {
        max-width:100%;
        margin:auto;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

This idea is to select CSS styles depending on the width (here we're using `min-width`, but there is also `max-width`). A good idea, is to express you sizes in percentages, that way, it can scale depending on the screen size.

Or you could start with a responsive template for starters and build upon it, like http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: i changed it with your  example..  i write two  diff.media queries but it take last one.please see edited quetion.